Question about math olympiad preparation
When I try to solve the exercises in a textbook that is written for math olympiads (specifically in India, as I'm Indian), I solve the easier questions fairly quickly and then when I get to problems that are harder compared to the easy ones, I find myself struggling and then procrastinate and don't pick the textbook up for weeks on end. I hate this and want to start the textbook again.
Also, I do the problems on A4-sized paper as when I do them in notebooks I get frustrated when I get them wrong or don't get them at all and normally rip the page out. I normally first try to solve the problems in rough and then formalize them on paper, but I get bored of formalizing them and procrastinate again. I don't want to leave them in rough as I am a perfectionist and maybe also have OCD.
I understand the theory, it's the exercises that I have trouble with. (especially number theory).
How much time should I spend on textbook questions like 'An Excursion in Mathematics'?
I also have a habit of buying a new textbook hoping that I will finally become good at olympiad math. I have two textbooks because of this, none of them completed. I am quite good at normal, high-school math.
EDIT: I'm in the 9th grade

I must have given the wrong impression about the textbooks. The textbooks are great and they are satisfying my curiosity. The only problem is that I can't really solve the problems that I think are basic and that I should be able to solve them.

Is it possible that you like the idea of being good at mathematics more than you like mathematics? If all you need is motivation, then ask one of your teachers to be a mentor who meets with you once a week to monitor your progress. This will put pressure on you to do the work. They may also be able to help with the problems on which you are stuck.

I don't think thats true, but its not so far-fetched either. Is there some way to check if what you are saying ist true?


Do you really like math olympiad ?

And more important :

Why do you want to go through olympiads ?

It is by passion, by anger, by competitive behaviour, by curiosity, seeking an identity ? Or something else.
It could help to question you on such motivation (s). Because I know what it is to buy several books, thinking you will get into, like intronized by the book themselves to gain the identity of a math olympic fan.
My opinion is that if you don't have the true feeling to be playing while doing maths olympiad, you may force you into non-sane practice. But if anyway what I write doesnt resonate with you, go forward, and think on a "discipline mode", thing I personnally don't like a lot in its meaning of suppressing passion.
Could Try :

Atomic habits : learning even a small thing by day is great (but it remains an artificial method)

Also allow you to :

Take time : maths isn't just a brute-force work-and-solve machine. Depending on people, it takes time to anchor and to provide a future possibility for intutive solving based on experience and personal sensitivity for maths. Maths is also an art.
Do other things like being with your friends or in nature or what you love, because a fresh mind can see solutions where a trained but tired cannot.

I wish you the best, also for finalization, think about the true meaning of procrasination. Internet is infested with the idea that you should what you want now and if you dont succeed and delay it, "you're a piece of sh*t". But no, maths isn't like this, life isn't like this, love isn't like this. Do you take your lunch of the following day, the day before to not procrastinate ? Maths, especially in olympiads must remains a pleasure and a passion, otherwise its called masochism under the pressure of constant performance edicted by a pesudo-Zeitgeist namely : "be more efficient it is the way to happiness".
Finally
Practice with others people in clubs, or whatever the form is. Maths is a community and from the very beginning to modern maths there always have been various exchange between people. Work with others !
Hope it helps and you will find pleasant way to live with.

I believe that I want to go through olympiads because 1) I want a future in math (because I love it) and all the best mathematicians have gone through the olympiads at some point of their life and 2) I am seeking an identity, as you said. I read Atomic habits and found in it amazing techniques, but quickly forgot the strategies.

Atomic habit is a method and personally I don't like to follow life-method. I will recommend you to plractice math with people, to go to a Math Club (we have several good in France, there may be some in your country). Math is also very important to practice with others, not solely alone. The force of a common project/or practice can foster your motivation.
